# changing the association of a contact

Tags: 2.3-gingerbread, contacts, verizon-backup-assistant

How do I change the account which stores a contact?

Right now, a lot of my contacts are associated with "Backup Assistant".  I no longer have Verizon so this is useless (and it throws a lot of errors, presumably because it is no longer authorized to talk to the Verizon server) and I would like to switch all my contacts to be stored with Google.  If I have to I will just delete each contact and re-create it with the new assocation, but is there an easier way to do this?  If I try to tap or long-tap on the "Backup Assistant Contact" header when I edit the contact, nothing happens.

Also, if I do have to re-create a new contact, is there some way to create the new contact on Google first, then delete it from Backup Assistant?  When I try to create the new contact first, attempting to delete it from my phone tells me I am going to delete it on multiple accounts.

Answer (score 1):

First, export your contacts.  From the Contacts app, touch the menu button and select Import/Export.  Then choose to export to SD.  Then from the SD card, transfer the file to your computer (I used Dropbox).  At this point I simply deleted all the contacts off my phone.  I get an error notifications that sync had failed because too many contacts had been deleted, but when I tapped on it, it gave me the option to go ahead and delete them on Google.

Then I went to Google Contacts and imported all my contacts.  Then I did a bit of cleanup, and everything got synced back to my phone.